# How to get sub-arrays containing same elements from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sub-array

I have an array containing duplicate elements. What I need is to get those duplicate elements to new sub-arrays.

For example:

```
I have the main array, array = [ a, b, c, a, d, c, c, b, a ]

what I need is to get this array divide into new sub-arrays dynamically like below:

subArray1 = [ a,a,a]
subArray2 = [b,b]
subArray3 = [c,c,c]
subArray4 = [d]
```

Thanks.

Comment: what you tried so far ? include your work

Comment: I am trying to get subarrays of all duplicate values from an array where many duplicate values and unique values present

Comment: Did you write any code?

Comment: No I need the code

Comment: This is not code writing service, You should try something first, Maybe you could find any solution by yourself...

Comment: I have tried a lot but not finding any, sorry for that

Comment: Add anything you have tried. Everyone is here to help, so any code you write will be used as a starting to help you get the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a'];

function divide(array) {
    let allArrays = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       if(!allArrays.flat().includes(array[i])) 
       allArrays.push(array.filter(el => el === array[i]));
    }
    return allArrays;
}

let [subArray1,subArray2,subArray3,subArray4] = divide(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could group the array by the values.

```js
const
    array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'a'],
    grouped = Object.values(array.reduce((r, v) => {
        (r[v] ??= []).push(v);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(grouped);
```